# How to handle page maintenance with spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jboss

Does anyone have expirience with maintenance page using spring MVC? What I am currently doing is I have one shell script which copies index.html and css to web app root folder, and when they are done with copying the maintanence site is displayed.

In meantime I do changes I delete classes and upload the new ones and then delete html and css files and everything is back to normal. This works on tomcat server, but when I tried this on jboss server, I get 404 page which is trying to point to index.jsp which naturally doesn't exist.

Is there a way to handle this more elegantly? I'm sure there must be, can someone share their expirience with this? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org) server in front which uses the [Tomcat Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) (als known as `mod_jk`) to delegate the requests to Tomcat/JBoss. Configure Apache HTTPD to display the desired maintenance page as 404/503 error page.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this - fully programmatic - solution:

[Spring-MVC interceptors](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/)